# Advice Setting Up an Android Phone for an Elderly User

Tags: contacts, accessibility, user-interface

My grandmother wants to use a smart phone but I'm struggling to set it up in a way that is intuitive for her.  Although she's used older mobile phones for decades, she doesn't have any experience with desktop computers or user interfaces and at 84 it's very difficult to pick up those metaphors.  She asked for a touch screen phone in the first place and I think feels some obligation to use it, so we'll pretend going back to a feature phone with physical buttons isn't an option, even though I think that would be the best choice.

All she really needs to be able to do is take calls, easily check missed calls and contacts, and access the dialer. Even text messaging isn't really important.

However far as I can tell Android isn't at all designed for someone like this.  The best I've been able to do so far is make contacts the only app on the home screen so there's always a clear way to get back to it (press the home button) and use the AOSP contacts app since it has a tab that displays favourites in large tiles with photos. The latter is really the only saving grace right now and what I'd like to aim for across the whole workflow since it's extremely visual and intuitive, all she has to do is tap on a picture of someone she knows to call them.  Even still, it's extremely easy to get lost in the rest of the UI; there are too many extraneous buttons, apps don't reset their state, and the few other apps that display large photos insist on opening menus instead of a one-tap dial.  the dialer is also an issue, I'm yet to find a way to put the keypad front and center instead of hidden behind a small bubble.

I've checked a number of alternative apps and launchers that advertise being easy to use for seniors but most replicate the same UI paradigm but with large, high-contrast buttons.  While I'm sure that's helpful for a lot of people the fundamental issue here isn't vision but struggling with the idea of buttons and menus in the first place.

I'm wondering if anyone else has faced this kind of problem and what kind of solutions you found.  I'd appreciate any advice or app recommendations.  I'm actually quite surprised there's no existing ultra-streamlined UI for the sake of accessibility.

Comment: There are Android phones designed for elderly people. The usually have their own UI and make it difficult to leave this area so the elderly users don't accidentally get to the underlaying Android system. Alternatively you can try to simplify Android by using a special launcher app that only provides a limited set of features and has large fonts and buttons.

Comment: Realme UI has simple mode, which is somewhat related https://c.realme.com/in/post-details/1490981450181246976